# mirc $regsubex replace () value

Tags: scripting, mirc

```
set %some1 (2)
set %some2 (3)
```

Now can i get the value of some1 which is in the brackets and change it to something else using $regsubex

So anyone can help?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$regex()` to get the numeric value inside the parenthesis:

```
; find the value
noop $regex(%some1, (\d+))

; print the value
echo -a Value: $regml(1)
```

Will print:

```
2
```

Likewise, you can use the same regex but with `$regsub()` this time to change that value:

```
; replace the value inside the () and put it back in %some
noop $regsub(%some1, (\d+), 98765, %some1)

; print that value
echo -a %some1
```

Will print:

```
(98765)
```